# Add "Align Center" button to a custom `Palette`

Tags: formatting, palettes

I have the following `Palette`:

```
CreatePalette[Column[
   (Button[Style[#1, 20, FontFamily -> "Calibri"], 
          FrontEndTokenExecute[InputNotebook[], "Style", #1], 
          Appearance -> "Palette", ImageSize -> 250] & ) /@ 
     {"Title", "Subtitle", "Subsubtitle", "Section", 
       "Subsection", "Subsubsection", "Text", 
       "DisplayFormula", "DisplayFormulaNumbered"}, 
   Spacings -> 0]];
```

I want to add two buttons, after `"DisplayFormula"` and `"DisplayFormulaNumbered"`, that display the test `(centred)` and which format the cells as `Format->DisplayFormula + Format->Text Alignment->Align Center` and `Format->DisplayFormulaNumbered + Format->Text Alignment->Align Center` respectively.

How do I do this?

If it's not possible to create one button for two formatting instructions, then how do I add a button that performs `Format->Text Alignment->Align Center`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One way is to edit the stylesheet for your notebook to add two new styles:`DisplayFormulaNumberedCenter` and `DisplayFormulaCenter`. Then you can use the same code by adding these two items to your list.

1. Select your notebook
2. Go to Format>Edit Stylesheet
3. Enter a style name (one of the two above) + ENTER
4. Select the cell where it appears and select `Cell>Show Expression`
5. Replace the full expression by the one below corresponding to your style. These are copies of the definitions in the default notebook for their uncentered counterparts, modified with the name of the new style and the center alignment.
6. `Cell>Show Expression` to go back to normal display
7. Repeat for the other style
8. Close (or intstall) the style sheet
9. The notebook now recognizes the new styles

The code for DisplayFormulaCenter:

```
Cell[StyleData["DisplayFormulaCenter"],
 CellMargins->{{66, Inherited}, {Inherited, Inherited}},
 StripStyleOnPaste->True,
 DefaultFormatType->DefaultInputFormatType,
 HyphenationOptions->{"HyphenationCharacter"->"\[Continuation]"},
 LanguageCategory->"Formula",
 ScriptLevel->0,
 SingleLetterItalics->True,
 MenuSortingValue->1700,
 FontFamily->"Source Sans Pro",
 FontSize->14,
 FontColor->GrayLevel[0.2],
 TextAlignment->Center,
 UnderoverscriptBoxOptions->{LimitsPositioning->True}]
```

The code for DisplayFormulaNumberedCenter:

```
Cell[StyleData["DisplayFormulaNumberedCenter", StyleDefinitions -> StyleData["DisplayFormula"]],
 CellFrameLabels->{{None, 
    Cell[
     TextData[{"(", 
       CounterBox["DisplayFormulaNumberedCenter"], ")"}], "DisplayFormulaEquationNumber"]}, {None, None}},
 CounterIncrements->"DisplayFormulaNumberedCenter", TextAlignment->Center,
 MenuSortingValue->1710]
```

[image]

Comment: Many thanks @Jean-Pierre. Can I ask a follow-up before marking this as answered? Is there a way to do this globally, or are stylesheets by definition notebook-specific?

Comment: With the stylesheet open in ```Edit Stylesheet```, click ```Install Stylesheet``` and save it under a name of your choice, such as ```CenteredFormula```. Now the style sheet is listed in the munu under ```Format>Stylesheet``` and can be selected for any notebook that is using the Default stylesheet (assuming the new stylesheet was created from the Default stylesheet, but it could be created from other stylesheets).

Comment: Fantastic. Many thanks.

Comment: Note that for the numbered version, you may wish to use the same counter for the center and left alignment. This requires modifying the code to: ```CounterBox["DisplayFormulaNumbered"]``` and ```CounterIncrements->"DisplayFormulaNumbered"```

Comment: Thanks so much @Jean-Pierre. I just added an uptick to your answer. I really appreciate the extra info.